# How do I access the Azure function present in one subscription into another subscription?

Tags: azureportal

I have two subscriptions in the Azure Portal.
One is for development and the other is for production.

I want to shift the logic apps created within development subscription to production subscription.
I have in total 5 logic apps. There is a main logic app and other four are sub logic apps.
I also have an Azure function within the development subscription.

Now, as far as I know, to deploy the main logic app to the production subscription, the production subscription should also have access to the Azure function present in the development subscription. However, currently I want to deploy only the logic apps to the production subscription and not the Azure function.

While I deploy the main logic app, I get an error as the Azure function is not accessed by the production subscription.

Can anyone help me with the issue?

I want to know, how do I provide access to production subscription to access the Azure function present in the development subscription without actually deploying the function to PROD.